# Vue Router - Accessing the Vue instance without calling next()

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm hacking at a way to push my SPA to a route if the for instance the validation fails. I'm using the `beforeRouteEnter` and `beforeRouteUpdate` methods to run a function to determine this;

```js
...
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    loading(next);
},
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    loading(next);
},
...
```

And then this function to validate (this is just temporary until I have this figured out).

```js
let loading = function(callback) {
    db.commit('setPageLoading', true);
    new requests().concat([
        'UserController@userDetails',
        'SettingController@settings',
        'ClientController@allClients',
        'StatsController@statsUsage',
        'UserController@paymentDetails'],
    () => {
        db.commit('setPageLoading', false);
        /** everything's all gravy, `next()` should be called now! */
        callback();
    },
    (error) => {
        /**
        * I dont want to call `next()` to access the vue instance as it will show the requested page
        * but I have to to access the router!!!
        **/
        callback(vm => {
            switch(error.response.status) {
                case 401:
                    /** Put login box here, this will do for now **/
                    vm.$router.push('/login').catch(err => {});
                break;
                /** Custom error to tell the SPA the user needs to fill in their company details first */
                case 498:
                    for(let i in error.response.data.errors) {
                        db.commit('addErrorNotification', error.response.data.errors[i][0]);
                    }
                    vm.$router.push('/profile').catch(err => {});
                break;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

My problem being I have to call `next()`to access the vue instance to push to a different route. But my calling the `next()` callback, it tells Vue Router to carry on loading the current or pending route which is not what I want to happen.

Can anyone tell me a way how I can access the Vue instance without calling the `next()` callback?

Regards

Comment: How about calling `next` with an argument, e.g. the route you want to push? E.g. `next('/profile')`.

Comment: Hi @DelenaMalan thanks for your comment. I'm sorry but I don't quite understand could you show me an example?

Comment: @DelenaMalan Because there is logic required to determine if/where to push to

Comment: @DelenaMalan Ah I understand now! I'll be back in a mo!

Comment: cool :) Wasn't sure if you had been aware that you can pass arguments to `next`. The supported arguments are listed [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards).

Comment: FWIW, you don't need Vue instance, you need router instance. It's available where you instantiated VueRouter.

Answer (score 0):

As described by Delena Malan, thank you!;

```js
let loading = function(callback) {
    db.commit('setPageLoading', true);
    new requests().concat([
        'UserController@userDetails',
        'SettingController@settings',
        'ClientController@allClients',
        'StatsController@statsUsage',
        'UserController@paymentDetails'],
    () => {
        db.commit('setPageLoading', false);
        /** everything's all gravy, `next()` should be called now! */
        callback();
    },
    (error) => {
        switch(error.response.status) {
            case 401:
                /** Put login box here, this will do for now **/
                callback({ path: '/login' });
            break;
            case 498:
                for(let i in error.response.data.errors) {
                    db.commit('setNotifications', []);
                    db.commit('addErrorNotification', error.response.data.errors[i][0]);
                }
                callback({ path: '/profile' });
            break;
        }
        db.commit('setPageLoading', false);
    });
};
```